# Having a trouble with embed youtube videos Swift Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, youtube

I am using WKWebView to view youtube videos. If I am typing my youtube video embed link within the app it works fine. But when I fetching youtube embed video code from firebase, youtube shows an error. I've checked in my console that i am receiving videocode and it is being successfully assigned to my variable for url link. I have no idea what is the problem with my Firebase and youtube

Please help me.

```
class VideoViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var videolink = ""

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!{
    didSet{
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchOffers()
    getVideo(videoCode: videolink)

}
func fetchOffers(){

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Helsinki")
    databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "bar_name").queryEqual(toValue: self.appDelegate.selectedBarName).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
            print("not found)")

        } else {
            print(snapshot.value!)
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "video")
                print(imageSnap)
                let dataDict = imageSnap.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                let videoLink = dataDict["videolink"] as! String
                self.videolink.append(videoLink)
                print("This is shit", self.videolink)
            }


        }
    })
}

func getVideo(videoCode:String){
    let url = URL(string: "https:/www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)")
    webView.load(URLRequest(url : url!))
}
```

[my youtube error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuEzA.png)

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem if you hardcode the value that you would otherwise read from Firebase? If so, you can rule out Firebase as a potential cause and significantly reduce the code that we need to understand. If you can't reproduce with a hardcoded value, that means the problem is in what you read from Firebase. Set a breakpoint on `print(imageSnap)` and check how the value you see there is different from the one you hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obvious. You are calling Async method to get the video code but did not wait to play. There are several ways to solve this.

An easy way is to move your call **getVideo(videoCode: videolink)** inside **fetchOffers** method like this:

```
print("This is shit", self.videolink)
self.getVideo(videoCode: videolink)
```

Another way is to pass a handler(closure) inside **fetchOffers** method like this, which will return String.

```
func fetchOffers(success: @escaping ((_ code: String) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((_ error: Error) -> Void)){

// same code just return success
print("This is shit", self.videolink)
success(videolink)
}
```

Now inside view controller call like this way:

```
fetchOffers(success:{[weak self] (code) in
        self?.getVideo(videoCode: code)
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
}
```